# create a index of sheets with hyperlink to those sheets

Tags: r, excel

I got a workbook which have hundreds of sheets with each having different data in it.

I want to create a index sheet having following type of data.

[image]

Such that when I click on 1 it will open Table 1 sheet and so on. 
I have created a data frame in such format and created a sheet using xlsx package but I am facing issue applying hyperlink as sheets to those index numbers.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: it would be useful if you could provide an example excel sheet.

Comment: This would be easier to do it within Excel: [Add a table of contents to your workbook](https://blogs.office.com/2011/01/13/add-a-table-of-contents-to-your-workbook-its-easy-i-promise/)

Comment: yeah I know, but I want to do it dynamically using R code.

Comment: @loki u can imagine any number of sheets with anything data in it.
I Just want to traverse through workbook using index numbers as I shown in above picture. Click on 2 and it will take me to link of worksheet associated with 2.

Answer (score 1):

Excel function: try this one.....

=hyperlink("[Book1.xlsx]"&$B2&"!A1",Rows(A$2:$A2))

[workbook name.extension] extension is important.

For Sheet name, function refers to cell b2 and then append range by adding A1. (! Completes sheet name)

Rows(A$2:$A2)) , Adds the display name for the hyperlink.

Copy and paste the formula in cell A2 of the index sheet.

Comment: The reference A$2:$A2 doesn't make sense to me, maybe you meant $A$2:$A2? Also, you can skip the file name if it's in the same file, and use `#` instead. Other than that I prefer this approach.

Comment: I don't see the $ sign as used making any variation in the final output. # tip is good..

Comment: It doesn't in this scenario, but it will if you copy to a different column. Why stick to a $ that has no meaning but may cause mistakes? I would change it to A$2:A2.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code and change as per your need, Make sure you have extra sheet with name "Index" before running this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub IndexGen()
    Dim WS_Count, i As Long

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    For i = 1 To WS_Count
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name <> "Index" Then
            Sheets("Index").Range("A" & i + 1) = i - 1
            Sheets("Index").Range("B" & i + 1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i + 1), Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name & "'" & "!" & "A1"

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is really nice answer but as I mentioned I want some help regarding R language implementation. May be with the help of in built function or another.

Answer (score 0):

If First sheet of excel file is Index file and starting from cell A$1 then use following code to provide hyperlink to other sheets A$1

```
wb <- loadWorkbook(excelOutputFileName)
sheets <- getSheets(wb)


rows <- getRows(sheets[[1]], rowIndex = NULL) 
cells <- getCells(rows, colIndex = 1)
for(rk in 1: (length(sheets)+1)){

  link <- paste0("'", names(sheets)[rk+1],"'", "!", "A", 1)

  addHyperlink(cells[[rk]], link, linkType="DOCUMENT")
}
```